# Specifying form for 'on form submit' trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I have two google forms, which send data to two tabs in a single spreadsheet.

I have set up a script with two functions.  I would like the first function to run on submission of the first form.  And, the second function to run on submission of the second form.

**Problem is:  when setting up a trigger onformsubmit, it does not allow you to specify which form.**

Therefore, whenever completing the first form, it runs both functions.

**Question: how can I restrict the functions from running only when the specific form is submitted?**

Comment: Have you tried to view the exact content of the eventInfo using the logger and see if you can find some form specific information in there ? I would have done it with pleasure but right now I have no computer... a cellphone is less than ideal to do such tests :-)  use Logger.log(e) in each function and test by sending form responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just looking at some documentation and found this:

[Documentation forForm](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#forForm(Form))

It states:

> Creates and returns a FormTriggerBuilder tied to the given form.

Also:

```
var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
     .forForm(form)
     .onFormSubmit()
     .create();
```

[onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit())

That code seems to be tied to a specific form.

Comment: If the error message is correct, then it's a server error, and not a problem with the code. But, it has happened before that the error message isn't totally correct.  If you think this is a bug or a problem at Google, you can report it on the Apps Script issue tracker:  [Link - Issue List](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)

Comment: If anything, the error message was super unhelpful. It's quite possible that it was a server error that lasted 2 days, but i'd be surprised. I'll add it to the tracker if I run into it again!

Answer (score 5):

As I suggested in the comments, you can determine the origin of the form submission by analyzing the response object's content.

Here is a basic example to illustrate : it will send you an email to tell which form has been submitted but you can of course use the same condition test to select the action you want to run.

```
function formSubmitOriginTest(e){
//  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
// example value : {"namedValues":{"Untitled Question 2":["test"],"Timestamp":["8/17/2014 11:22:47"]},"values":["8/17/2014 11:22:47","test"],"source":{},"range":{"rowStart":3,"rowEnd":3,"columnEnd":2,"columnStart":1},"authMode":{}}
  if(e.namedValues["Untitled Question 2"]!=undefined){// only form B has one question with this exact title, that's enough to identify it.
    MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),'form B has been submitted','');// optionally include the answers in the email body if you want
  }else{
    MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),'form A has been submitted','');// optionally include the answers in the email body if you want
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way this can be done is by looking at the `sheet` name that comes in the response's event object via the `range` property. Here's an example of how I determined the form that triggered the submission:

```
// set the sheet name that stores the form responses you care about here:
function getSourceSheetName() { return 'Form Responses 1'; }

function submit(eventObj) {
    var range = eventObj.range;

    var eventSourceSheetName = range.getSheet().getName();
    var givenSourceSheetName = getSourceSheetName();

    // if the source sheet (from form response sheet) is not the same as the specified form response sheet, quit (return) so extra forms don't trigger the code
    if (eventSourceSheetName.toUpperCase() !== givenSourceSheetName.toUpperCase() ) {
        Logger.log('A different form just submitted data - quit code');
        return;
    }

    // you now know which form submitted the response, so do whatever you want!
    // ... your code goes here
}
```

Basically, this code grabs the name of the sheet that the Form response comes from via `range.getSheet().getName()`. Next, it checks if that name is a specified name we're looking for (specified in the function `getSourceSheetName()`.

I think it's also possible to get the active sheet name via:

```
eventObj.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
```

In case you don't want to use "Range".

I hope this helps!