# Determine caller in Installable Script

Tags: forms, triggers, google-apps-script

I've create an installable script which creates forms on the fly for 2 to 3 party verification.  Since these forms are filled out asynchronously, and often in batches, it is important to determine which form called the function.

First the response form is created, then a trigger is installed.
CreateForm function:

```
    function createForm(title){
      var form = FormApp.create(title)
    //set parameters for new form
      form.setCollectEmail(true);  
      form.setShowLinkToRespondAgain(false);  
      ...
      return form;
    };
```

InstallTrigger function:

```
function InstallTrigger(form, funct) {
  var trigger= ScriptApp.newTrigger(funct)
  .forForm(form)
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create()
  return trigger.getUniqueId();
 };
```

During the initial form submit, a function called createMessage() creates an email based on responses and runs the two scripts above.  The email contains a link to the newly created form to await approval. To that point, everything works fine.

The problem comes when the newly installed trigger fires.  I haven't found a way to set the trigger source as a variable.  I'm sure that it has to do with an event, but the documentation on events doesn't go too far into forms from what I can see.  I read that it can be done ([Understanding Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)). I just don't quite understand where (e) is defined on an installable script.  Would it be in the install function or some other place?

Comment: have you read [this post ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227987/google-apps-script-specifying-form-for-on-form-submit-trigger/25348034#25348034) it might give you some clues. Try also to view in the logger the actual content of the event (use JSON.Stringify(event) in the logger.)

Comment: I just read through it.  I will add the JSON.Stringify(e) in the Logger.  If I understand correctly, it would look like 
`function triggerFunction(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.Stringify(e))
  var form = FormApp.openById(e.source.getId());
  ...
  }`

Comment: Yep :-)  try to find some element that is unique to one configuration then setup a condition on this element.

Comment: Made change so the function resembles what is above. The Logger.log() returns `Tue Sep 16 14:22:29 PDT 2014 INFO: {"response":{},"authMode":{}}`  The timestamp is from the Logger, so no useable info there.  I was hoping that there was a e.source as mentioned in the aforementioned article.

Comment: Mmmmmmh, sorry, no other idea for now...

Comment: Well, on a hunch I did a call for e.response.getEditResponseUrl() and it returned the URL, so I can change the `var form = FormApp.openById(e.source)` to `var form = FormApp.openByUrl(e.response.getEditUrl())` and it works.  Thanks again for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks again Serge inas for the walkthrough.

(e) is defined when the function defined.  In my example above, the InstallTrigger() function adds a trigger to the form passed to it. The script that executes on submission is also passed to it.  So, the installation of the trigger comes from a pre-installed onSubmit() trigger.  In the submission function, it calls

```
var NewForm = FormApp.createForm(); 
InstallTrigger(NewForm, triggerFunction);
```

The function "triggerFunction" should look something like this:

```
function triggerFunction (e) {
Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))
GmailApp.sendEmail("yourEmailString","Debugging",Logger.getLog() //sends an email to you with the logfile.
var form = FormApp.openByUrl(e.response.getEditResponseUrl());  
...
}
```

The e.source mentioned in the aforementioned article says that it works for installable triggers, but when enumerated, only the e.resource and e.authMode were available.  Fortunately, the e.response contains the method editUrl that can be used with the method .openByUrl() and return the original form.