# Multiple forms triggered to single sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a google spreadsheet that takes information from two different forms.

Manually triggering using the spreadsheet UI does not let you distinguish *which* form is specified when choosing "OnFormSubmit" in the triggers menu.

Thus, I am using the following code (for my sheet) to manage two different triggering events for two different form-submits:

```
function onOpen(e) {


var form = FormApp.openById('ID of Form 1');
 ScriptApp.newTrigger('onForm1Submit')
     .forForm(form)
     .onFormSubmit()
     .create();


var signup = FormApp.openById('[ID of Form 2]');
signup.setRequireLogin(true)
 ScriptApp.newTrigger('SignUpEvent')
     .forForm(signup)
     .onFormSubmit()
     .create();
}      
function SignUpEvent(e) {
\\stuff
}

function onForm1Submit(e) {
\\stuff
}
```

But when I do it this way, I am recieving a failure notification on form submit:

Function: UpdateLadder

Error Message: "Authorization is required to perform that action."

Trigger: "formSubmit"

First off, how am I recieving these email notifications to begin with? I didn't manually ask for email notifications of error messages. 
Secondly, what's the best way for me to get "authorization"?

Answer (score 1):

For the `onFormSubmit()` function, you can write code to match the destination sheet to a certain function.  For example, I have a spreadsheet that has 2 forms that both have sheets for destination within it.  In the `onFormSubmit()` trigger code, here is what I did:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log("[METHOD] onFormSubmit");
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var student = ss.getSheetByName("Student Requests");
  var studentId = student.getSheetId();
  var teacher = ss.getSheetByName("Teacher Requests");
  var teacherId = teacher.getSheetId();
  if (sheetId == studentId){
    sendStudentEmail(e.range);
  }
  if (sheetId == teacherId){
    sendTeacherEmail(e.range)
  } 
}
```

So, in this example, a Teacher can request using a form, and if the `onFormSubmit` is related to the Teacher form, then send the Teacher email, etc..

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably certain that onFormSubmit ties one spreadsheet to one form; it doesn't know what to do with two onFormSubmit triggers.

Comment: Here is where I got the idea:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227987/google-apps-script-specifying-form-for-on-form-submit-trigger

Do you think the answer given by Sandy Good won't work? 

If the problem is that I can only have 1-sheet per 1-form at one time,  can I flip-flop between which form is connected to the sheet?

How about on each on-form-submit event I change which form the sheet is triggered to?