# Manipulate google form associated with a google sheet from app script in that sheet

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I have a google spreadsheet which contains multiple sheets (or tabs) within it. Each sheet is populated from its own unique form. None of the forms are embedded in the spreadsheet.

Periodically, I need to delete all the data in the sheets, and also delete all the old responses which are saved in each of the forms. I can do this using a .gs script which resides in the spreadsheet. It accesses the form by its ID (the long string which appears in its URI). This requires the ID string to be hardcoded in my .gs script.

Ideally, I would like to access each form from the sheet object (i.e. the destination for each forms entries). Mock up code would look like this...

```
var ss = SpreadSheedApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var form = sheet.getMyAssociatedSourceForm(); // my dream method :-)
form.deleteAllResponses() // this method already exists
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? Or will I have to continue to use the ID (which is currently working)?

rgds...

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25227987/1677912?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this without literally typing in ID's into your script.  But, you would need to get every Form in your drive, loop through them all and get the `destinationId()` of every Form.

[Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getdestinationid)

Then compare the destinationId with the current spreadsheets ID, which you can get without needing to "hard code" it:

```
function deleteAllResponses() {
  var thisSS_ID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();

  var allForms = DriveApp.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS);
  var thisFormFile, thisFormFileID = "", thisForm, theDestID = "";

  while (allForms.hasNext()) {
    thisFormFile = allForms.next();
    thisFormFileID = thisFormFile.getId();
    thisForm = FormApp.openById(thisFormFileID);

    try {
      theDestID = thisForm.getDestinationId();
    } catch(err) {
      continue;
    };

    if (theDestID === "" || theDestID === undefined) {
      continue;
    };

    if (theDestID === thisFormFileID) {
      thisForm.deleteAllResponses();
    };
  };
};
```

I have not tested this, so don't know if it works.  If it does, let me know in the comments section.

Comment: Tks for your reply and you've point me towards a solution. You can't call deleteAllResponses() directly on the objects in the returned array/iterator above. You need to get the object's ID (`.gitId()`) and use `FormApp.openById()` to return an opened form. You can then call both `getDestinationId()` and `deleteAllResponses()` on this. BTW, you also need catch any forms lying around which have no destination assigned to them or this error will stop your script.