# Google Apps Script OnSubmit Function Triggered by Specific Form Submission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, form-submit, google-forms

I have the same question as the user here:
[Google Apps Script - specifying form for 'on form submit' trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227987/google-apps-script-specifying-form-for-on-form-submit-trigger)
2 forms tied to different tabs in a spreadsheet that I want to trigger 2 separate functions on submission of the respective form.

Following the answer given, I tried the following code but the functions did not trigger on the submission of those forms for some reason.

```
var form1 = FormApp.openById('FormID1');
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('OnForm1SubmitFunction')
   .forForm(form1)
   .onFormSubmit()
   .create();

OnForm1SubmitFunction() {
   blah;
}

var form2 = FormApp.openById('FormID2');
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('OnForm2SubmitFunction')
   .forForm(form2)
   .onFormSubmit()
   .create();

OnForm2SubmitFunction() {
   blah;
}
```

I could use the other solution given, which uses the standard formsubmit trigger event and a check on the submission fields, eg.
    if(e.namedValues["Untitled Question 2"]!=undefined)
to determine which form was submitted. But the first solution that ties the function trigger to a specific form, and allows separate functions triggered for each form submission, seems more elegant if I could get it to work.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying form for 'on form submit' trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227987/specifying-form-for-on-form-submit-trigger)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what I did wrong and got it working!
1) The OnSubmit Functions should receive an argument e,
2) The creation of the triggers should be in an initialization function, and
3) I was using the incorrect Form ID (didn't realise the form edit and view IDs were different!)