# onFormSubmit trigger won't install in add-on

Tags: google-apps-script

This is a question about an onFormSubmit() installable trigger in a Google Sheets **Add-on**. I have tried everything and I cannot figure out why this trigger won't install from the add-on.

I know a user can have only one of each trigger type in an add-on, this is the only one. I don't think that's the issue. The user has full access to both the spreadsheet file and the form. The add-on is installed and enabled.

It just won't install. What am I missing? Any help would be appreciated.

---

```
function verificationON() {  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var headingspage = ss.getSheetByName('headings')  
  var formID = headingspage.getRange('C6').getValue()
  var form = FormApp.openById(formID)
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('formVerificationEmail')
                         .forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create()}
```

Comment: Have you viewed the "Execution Transcript?"  From the "view" menu, choose "Execution Transcript" after running the code.  At the bottom of the log there will be a message about whether the code executed successfully or not, and if not what line the error is on.  When installing a trigger for an Add-on, the code should always look for an existing trigger with the same name.  If an existing trigger is found, then either don't install a new one, or delete the existing and create new.  [Link to Apps Script troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting)

Comment: Did you include an onInstall(e) function on your add-on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function myFunction() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID');
var range = sheet.getLastRow(); //Get Last Row with Data
var datas = sheet.getSheets()[0];
var startRow = range + 1; // First row of data to process
var numRows = 1; // Number of rows to process

var dataRange = datas.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows);

// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i = data.length; ++i) {
var row = data[i];
var firstName = row[0]
var lastName = row[1]
var dateAdded = row[2]
if(firstName == ""){
datas.getRange(startRow + i, 1).setValue(startRow);
datas.getRange(startRow + i, 2).setValue("Me");
datas.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(new Date());
}
};
var form = FormApp.openById('FORM_ID');
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
.forForm(form)
.onFormSubmit()
.create();
}
```

This sample code will enter a value on the last row.

To check the installed trigger(Go to *Resources* > *Current project's trigger*/*All you trigger*):

[image]

Here are some related documents that may help you:

- [Google Apps Script - specifying form for 'on form submit' trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227987/google-apps-script-specifying-form-for-on-form-submit-trigger)
- [Apps Script tutorial](https://zapier.com/learn/google-sheets/google-apps-script-tutorial/)