# Wrong source and response in form triggers

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I set a simple workflow with a Google Apps Script. I created the script project from a form A.

Here is the workflow:

1. users submit a response for the form A
2. the script creates a new response for the form B, submit it, and sends me the edition link by email
3. I submit the response for the form B the script created for me
4. the script sends me a recap of both form by email

To do so I have programmatically set up a trigger on the form B:

```
function addOnNewFormBSubmitTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onNewFormBSubmit')
    .forForm(FORM_B_ID)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}
```

The function `onNewFormBSubmit` looks like that:

```
function onNewFormBSubmit(formSubmitEvent) {
  _sendAnalysisEmail(formSubmitEvent.source, formSubmitEvent.response);
}
```

The function is triggered but the the `formSubmitEvent.source` value is the form A and `formSubmitEvent.response` is the latest response for this form. I would expect the source to be the form B, as I attached the trigger on it.

**EDIT:**

Even passing a form instance instead of its ID does not work as I expect it

```
function addOnNewAlaysisSubmitTrigger() {
  var form = FormApp.openById(FORM_B_ID);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onNewFormBSubmit')
    .forForm(form)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Form response triggers are not activated by programmatic submission.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @tehhowch, the link you gave me in the comments made me think that it may work if the script is not created from the Form. Thus I made a POC creating the script from a Spreadsheet and it works.

This is the script I made: [Google Apps Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eWH6.png)

And these are the logs generated by the two functions: [function call logs from Stackdriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arb3d.png)

As you can see I get two different responses submitted from the two forms.
Now the problem is that the event is not a submit form event as defined in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit_4 but this is another story.

If you want to try, here are:

- the spreadsheet from where I created the forms and the script (logs are pushed in the "logs" sheet): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17pFDXlYpOjXgaN5ZsBYimrBZHl6WPcmUvMrAjAnc9ys/edit?usp=sharing
- the live form A (Google sign in required): https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSff7ISYkqLtPwtzTWw2Iwxmm4dIax7z9ye9EeLY9SxDz3vJvw/viewform?usp=sf_link
- the live form B (Google sign in required too): https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc1HrswTr6prGxBBwy2a4Nqs1pyF7CJTjk2HafZyXsTtdnaXQ/viewform?usp=sf_link
- the script : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17pFDXlYpOjXgaN5ZsBYimrBZHl6WPcmUvMrAjAnc9ys/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Form as parameter instead of just his Id.

Something like that:

```
var form = FormApp.openById('FORM_B_ID');
ScriptApp.newTrigger('onNewFormBSubmit')
    .forForm(form)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
```

Comment: yes I did and it has the same result unfortunately :(

Comment: @BenjaminGrandfond Given https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227987/specifying-form-for-on-form-submit-trigger this seems to be the right way to go about it